# How is the Filipino expression “salamat” related to the Arabic?

Tags: etymology, arabic, tagalog

Salamat in Filipino means “thank you”.

> In the Arabic form, the word is in the feminine plural salāmat سلامت from the singular salāmah . Salamat in Arabic is equivalent to peace and blessings (a greeting or plural greeting). In Hebrew, סלמאת is slang for "Goodbye".

It says “Salamat is equivalent to the greet to peace and blessings”, in other words in expressions like “ As-*salamu alaykum* (Arabic: ٱلسَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ‎, as-salāmuʿalaykum) “ which is basically “Greetings/blessings be with you”. In most Arabic cultures, they use “Shukran” when thanking someone. It comes from the root verb “شكر” “shakara” meaning “to thank”.

I am just wondering how the Filipinos managed to adopt the form of “salamat” to mean “thank you”.

Comment: I don't know where you found the indented text, but "feminine plural salāmat سلامت from the singular salāmah" is total nonsense. salāmat and salāmah are two spellings of the same word. They are both singular.

Answer (score 6):

It's only in some languages including English that saying “thank you” means “I express gratitude to you”. In many languages something like “be thou blessed” is said instead. For example, in Russian “thank you” is [*спасибо*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE) (spasibo) [spɐˈsʲibə] which is actually a contraction of *спаси Бо[г]* meaning “save (you) God”.

Arabic سَلَامَات‎ (salāmāt) is plural of سَلَامَة‎ (salāma) “good health”. Generally speaking, there is nothing strange to say “blessings!”, or “good health to you!” or “God save you!” instead of “I appreciate you”, so why wouldn't Filipinos do that? Besides, since those phrases are actually ritual, there's no great difference in what you actually say for something good done to you, the point is to show your respect for that in a way the surrounding culture accepts.

Compare “thank you” in some other languages and note what different things it can in fact mean:

> • [French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merci#French): *merci* /mɛʁ.si/ “mercy, grace”, from Middle French *merci, mercy*, from Old French *merci*, from Latin *mercēdem*, accusative singular of *mercēs* (“wages, fee, price”)
> • [Tibetan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%BD%90%E0%BD%B4%E0%BD%82%E0%BD%A6%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%A2%E0%BE%97%E0%BD%BA%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%86%E0%BD%BA#Tibetan): ཐུགས་རྗེ་ཆེ (thugs rje che) from ཐུགས་རྗེ (thugs rje, “compassion”) +‎ ཆེ (che, “great”)
> • [Mongolian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B0#Mongolian): баярлалаа [pairˈɮa] “rejoice”
> • [Turkish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sa%C4%9F_olun#Turkish) (formal): *sağ olun* from *sağ* “right, alive, healthy” *olun* “be you”
> • Moroccan Arabic: برْكة الله فيك‎ (bərka llæh fik, literally “God bless you”), الله يبرْك فيك‎ (llæh ibərk fik, literally “God bless you”), الله يرْحم وليدك‎ (llæh irḥəm wəlidək, literally “God have mercy upon your parents”)
> • [Cebuano](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salamat#Cebuano): salamat
> • [Hiligaynon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salamat#Hiligaynon): salamat

Comment: The problem is; in English *to be blessed* and *to show gratitude* are not the exact same thing, *to be be blessed* like in the arabic meaning means more like “be healthy; prosperous; wealthy”, *I appreciate you* / *I’m showing gratitude to you* has a slightly different nuance to that in modern times. I would expect something like “be thou blessed” to be an inexplicit way of thanking someone in the olden times. I’m thinking more of an Indonesian or indo-malay influence (arabic culture) on the language of the Philippines, as it is an austroneasian language.

Comment: @Ere - Again: since those phrases are actually ritual, there's no great difference in what you actually say for something good done to you. Nobody actually thinks about what those thanksgiving phrases actually mean. In Soviet Union where all religion was actually banned from public life, nobody cared to substitute the Russian _спасибо_ for something less religious, _because nobody cares and nobody pays attention to how gratitude is expressed_, you either express it or not, that's all.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but since there is no data or supporting evidence to go with it; from a linguistic point of view - I’d say it is based on speculation.

Comment: you can “thank” someone but not appreciate or be greatful for it and vice-versa. It is essentially a nicety in the former.

Comment: None of those are even etymologically related (except the last 3) especially the first one , what root does the french *merci* share with the OP’s q? You’re just listing the etymologies of how thank you is said in different languages, I think the OP is looking for an etymological relationship.

Comment: @aesking - OP is looking for an etymological relationship, but wrote the etymology of _selamat_ in the question? The etymology is clear, the question is about why _selamat_ meaning “good health” in Arabic came to mean “thank you” in Filipino. In my answer, I explain the connection and cite other languages in order to show that “thank you” can be expressed in _very different_ ways, not necessarily including the words for gratitude.

Comment: OP literally put “austronesian languages” in the first comment and what he/she was asking for. He/she is asking how the meaning of salamat came to be, both in terms of its original etymology and the etymology of **closely related** languages. You were citing examples in French and Russian ...

Comment: @aesking - The part about “austronesian languages” was added to the question after I had already posted my answer, so when I saw the addition, I added examples from Cebuano and Hiligaynon which are Austronesian languages. Indonesian and Malay are **not closely related** to Filipino, not mutually understandable, and Filipinos are Christians (92%), not Muslims. If you have something to say, you're welcome to give your own answer, I've already given mine, and I see no need in giving any more explanations. _Dixi._

Comment: @YellowSky fair enough. Btw, all those **92% christians** still use an Arabic based expression to say “thank you”; “salamat” is universally Standard. So I don’t see your point. The language is still affected because of the cultural influence Islam has had in the past regardless of what religion most people identify as now. The rest of that ~8% is **5.1 million muslims living in parts of Mindanao, Palawan, and the Sulu**. The Arabic script is still even used in these areas. Philippines just has a very large population. Philippines has **120-187 distinct languages**; Tagalog being the standard.

Comment: I would argue the Mongolian means "I just rejoiced" or sth similar. Right now it looks a bit like imperative which it certainly is not.

Answer (score 1):

The Tagalog region in the Philippine island of Luzon was a Muslim Sultanate before the Spanish conquered Luzon and the other islands.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question at all.